# how to add a character in a field of a table that has data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

The question is:
I need to add a character in the field of a table that already has data.

example, I want to add a (-) to a string that looks like this:

```
   **000032872634JFEO099**
```

the changed format is:

```
   **0-00032872634JFEO099**.
```

is there a way to do it in microsoft sql 2012?

Comment: what would be the proper way to make this update to the table ?

Comment: Is there more logic to it or just adding a dash after the first character? If that's it, check out @Tim Biegeleisen's answer. If it's not, however, please explain more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `STUFF` function is a good option here:

```
SELECT STUFF('000032872634JFEO099', 2, 0, '-');

0-00032872634JFEO099
```

### Demo

If you want to do an update, then use the same logic:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET col = STUFF(col, 2, 0, '-');
```

Comment: just wanting to add `SELECT STUFF('**000032872634JFEO099**', 4, 0, '-');` to include the `**`

Comment: @maSTAShuFu I wasn't sure about those stars, but thought it would be easy enough for the OP to modify what I wrote.